# Cant start debugging session using ServiceBase

Tags: c#, visual-studio, service

Im trying to debug a Windows service using ServiceProcess.ServiceBase as opposed to installing the service locally.  I have a small console app in my project with a method like so

```
static void Main()
{
    ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
    ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
    { 
        new MyProcessorService() 
    };
    ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
}
```

This project is part of a solution, so I set this project to be the startup, set some breakpoints and hit F5, yet I still get the message about not being able to debug the service... "*Cannot start service from the command line or a debugger....*"

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot start a service in an interactive context (unless the service user has rights to do so).

```
if (Environment.UserInteractive)
{
    //Instantiate service object and call a method to start the service manually here...
}
else
{
    //Normal ServiceBase.Run goes here....
}
```

That manual startup method on your `ServiceBase` derived class will typically look something like:

```
 internal void TestStartupAndStop(string[] args)
 {
     this.OnStart(args);
     Console.ReadLine();
     this.OnStop();
 }
```

Comment: I have full admin rights on my workstation and Im sure Ive seen it done without checking the Interactive context.  For example http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10153/Debugging-Windows-Services-under-Visual-Studio-NET and this is an example of what Im trying to do.

Comment: I believe this is a better option as it doesn't depend on compiler directives. Plus it actually executes using the `ServiceBase` methods you would use for starting/stopping your service opposed to having to expose more implementation detail to the world through an extra public method.

Comment: Thank you.  I got rid of my console app, and added back the Main method into the service class.  Then wired up the check for UserInteractive.  I can debug and step into my code now without bothering to install the service.